# EF Core difference between AsEnumerable and AsAsyncEnumerable

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ienumerable, iqueryable, iasyncenumerable

Are there any differences in behavior or performance between `AsEnumerable`, `AsAsyncEnumerable` and simple iteration over `IQueryable` in EF Core?

```cs
// Using .AsEnumerable();
var blogs = context.Posts.Where(p => p.Title.StartsWith("A").AsEnumerable();
foreach (var blog in blogs)
{
    // ...
}
```

```cs
// Just iterating over IQueryable;
var blogs = context.Posts.Where(p => p.Title.StartsWith("A");
foreach (var blog in blogs)
{
    // ...
}
```

```cs
// Using .AsAsyncEnumerable();
var blogs = context.Posts.Where(p => p.Title.StartsWith("A").AsAsyncEnumerable();
await foreach (var blog in blogs)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: In actuality, whenever IO happens, _something is buffered_ - per-item "streaming" would otherwise be very inefficient.

Comment: Can you give more details and/or an example? @Dai

Comment: When using a remote database server over TCP/IP, then (at least) each packet will be buffered - when using an in-proc DB like Sqlite then IO will be buffered per-page, and so on...

Comment: Good question, I am not sure it is closed. When you use IQueryable you use LINQ to entities and actually the query do not executed until you do not enumerate them. After enumeration of them using any of the method, the query executed on data source and you can use LINQ to object. If you use simply AsEnumerable or AsAsyncEnumerable it is not materialized until you truly use them using foreach (async foreach) but in case of ToList, ToArray and ToListAsync, they are materialized just after using the method